# Problem with my PDF reader on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I have a problem with my PDF reader on google chrome. When I open a PDF file, then it appear and fail few second after. [I made a video to illustrate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scbow915XMo&feature=youtu.be). Any one already had this problem ? Could it be mac computor ? I've got a MacBook pro from 2011. But on safari it works well, so it should be a problem with Chrome (and it's very recent in the sense that I have this problem since 2 weeks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known Chrome bug described at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=870404.

You can add a star to that issue to be notified of the fix.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I hope they'll fix it soon :)